# React/Postgres sql detail: 'Failing row contains (43, ccc, null, 0, 2022-07-01 15:37:11.631)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, database, postgresql

**I am getting the error when I am connecting the frontend code as well as backend code with the database maybe the problem might be in front end but pls let me know the meaning of the error because I am newbie.I am getting the error on register pls help me and also when I register the website using frontend it shows me error on **localhost/register

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkCf9.png)

```
 const express = require('express');
    const { listen } = require('express/lib/application');
    const bodyParser=require('body-parser');
    const bcrypt=require('bcrypt-nodejs')
    const cors = require('cors')
    const knex = require('knex');
    const { response } = require('express');
    
    const db=knex({
        client: 'pg',
        connection: {
          host : '127.0.0.1',
          user : 'postgres',
          password : '224898',
          database : 'smart-brain'
        }
      });
     
    
    const app = express();
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(cors())
    
    const database={
        users:[
            {
                id:'123',
                name:'John',
                email:'John@gmail.com',
                password:'ABC',
                entries:0,
                joined:new Date()
            },
    
        
            {
                id:'124',
                name:'ABC',
                email:'ABC',
                password:'123',
                entries:0,
                joined:new Date()
            }
        ],
        login:[
            {
                id:'987',
                hash:'',
                email:'John@gmail.com'
            }
        ]
    }
    
    app.get('/' ,(req,res)=>{
        res.send(database.users);
    })
    
    
    app.post('/signin',(req,res)=>{
        if(req.body.email===database.users[0].email && req.body.password===database.users[0].password){
            res.json(database.users[0]);
        }else{
            res.status(400).json('error login in');
        }
    })
    
    app.post('/register',(req,res)=>{
        const{email,name,password}=req.body;
       db('users')
       .returning('*')
       .insert({
        email:email,
        name:name,
        joined: new Date()
       })
       .then(user=>{
        res.json(user[0]);
       })   
       . catch(err => console.log(err))
        
    })
    
    
    app.get('/profile/:id',(req,res)=>{
        const{id}=req.params;
        let found=false;
        database.users.forEach(user=>{
            if(user.id===id){
                found=true;
                return res.json(user);
            }
        })
        if(!found){
            res.status(400).json('not found');
        }
    })
    
    app.put('/image',(req,res)=>{
        const{id}=req.body;
        let found=false;
        database.users.forEach(user=>{
            if(user.id===id){
                found=true;
                user.entries++
                return res.json(user.entries);
            }
        })
        if(!found){
            res.status(400).json('not found');
        }
    })
    
    
    
    // // Load hash from your password DB.
    // bcrypt.compare("bacon", hash, function(err, res) {
    //     // res == true
    // });
    // bcrypt.compare("veggies", hash, function(err, res) {
    //     // res = false
    // });
    
    
    app.listen(3000,()=>{
        console.log('app is running on port 3000 ');
    })
```

AND ALSO I AM SHARING FRONTEND APP.JS CODE

APP.js code

```
import './App.css';
import Navigation from './Components/Navigation/Navigation';
import FaceRecognition from './Components/FaceRecognition/FaceRecognition';
import Logo from './Components/Logo/Logo'
import ImageLinkForm from './Components/ImageLinkForm/ImageLinkForm'
import Rank from './Components/Rank/Rank'
import { Component } from 'react';
import Particles from "react-tsparticles";
import { loadFull } from "tsparticles";
import SignIn from './Components/SignIn/SignIn';
import Register from './Components/Register/Register'


const USER_ID = 'aad';
const PAT = 'bd69e06e68f244ed83b9ce09ee560e7c';
const APP_ID = 'aaa';
const MODEL_ID = 'face-detection';
const MODEL_VERSION_ID = '45fb9a671625463fa646c3523a3087d5';




const particlesOption = {
  fpsLimit: 120,
  particles: {
    links: {
      color: "#ffffff",
      distance: 150,
      enable: true,
      opacity: 0.5,
      width: 1,
    },
    collisions: {
      enable: true,
    },
    move: {
      direction: "none",
      enable: true,
      outModes: {
        default: "bounce",
      },
      random: true,
      speed: 5,
      straight: true,
    },

  },
  detectRetina: true,
}

const particlesInit = async (main) => {
  await loadFull(main);
};


const initialState = {
  input: '',
  imageUrl: '',
  box: {},
  route:'signin',
  isSignedIn:false,
  user: {
    id: '',
    name: '',
    email: '',
    joined: '',
    entries: 0
  }

};
class App extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = initialState;
  };
  loadUser = (data) => {
    this.setState({
      user: {
        id: data.id,
        name: data.name,
        email: data.email,
        entries: data.entries,
        joined: data.joined
      }
    })
  }
 
   


 


  
  apiData = () => {
    const raw = JSON.stringify({
      "user_app_id": {
        "user_id": USER_ID,
        "app_id": APP_ID
      },
      "inputs": [
        {
          "data": {
            "image": {
              "url": this.state.input
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    });

    const requestOptions = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Key ' + PAT
      },
      body: raw
    };

    return requestOptions;
  }

  displayFaceBox = (box) => {
    this.setState({ box: box });
  }



  onInputChange=(event) =>{
    this.setState({input: event.target.value});
  }

  
  onImageSubmit = () => {
    this.setState({ imageUrl: this.state.input });
    const requestOptions = this.apiData();
    fetch("https://api.clarifai.com/v2/models/" + MODEL_ID + "/versions/" + MODEL_VERSION_ID + "/outputs", requestOptions)
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(result => JSON.parse(result))
      .then(obj => {
        if (obj) {
          fetch('http://localhost:3000/image', {
            method: 'put',
            headers: {'content-type': 'application/json'},
            body: JSON.stringify({
                id: this.state.user.id
            })
          })
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(count => {
            this.setState(Object.assign(this.state.user, {entries: count}))
          })
        }
        this.displayFaceBox(this.calculateFaceLocation(obj))
      })
      .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
  }

  calculateFaceLocation = (data) => {
    const clarifaiFace = data.outputs[0].data.regions[0].region_info.bounding_box;
    const image = document.getElementById('inputimage');
    const width = Number(image.width);
    const height = Number(image.height);
    return ({
      leftCol: clarifaiFace.left_col * width,
      topRow: clarifaiFace.top_row * height,
      rightCol: width - (clarifaiFace.right_col * width),
      bottomRow: height - (clarifaiFace.bottom_row * height),
    })
  }


  onRouteChange=(route)=>{
    if(route==='signout'){
      this.setState({isSignedIn:false})
    }else if(route==='home'){
      this.setState({isSignedIn:true})
    }
    this.setState({route:route})
  }
  render(){

    const { imageUrl,  box ,isSignedIn,route} = this.state;
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Particles className='particles'
          init={particlesInit}
          options={particlesOption}
        />
    
      <Navigation isSignedIn={isSignedIn} onRouteChange={this.onRouteChange} />{ route==='home'?
      <div>

       <Logo />
       <Rank name={this.state.user.name} entries={this.state.user.entries}/>  

        <ImageLinkForm onInputChange={this.onInputChange}
              onImageSubmit={this.onImageSubmit}/>
      
      <FaceRecognition box={box} imageUrl={imageUrl} />
      </div>   :(
        route==='signin'?
        <SignIn loadUser={this.loadUser} onRouteChange={this.onRouteChange} />
        : <Register  loadUser={this.loadUser}onRouteChange={this.onRouteChange}/>
      )
      
     
    }
    </div>
  );
}
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Do not use images for textual information, copy and paste the text into the question. This would make the following easier.
2. From error message `code:23502`. If you go here [Error codes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/errcodes-appendix.html) you find that corresponds to `23502    not_null_violation`. So the value that is being set to `NULL` is being entered into a column that has `NOT NULL` set. Your choices are:

   a) Make sure the value is not set to `NULL`.

   b) If you can have `NULL` values in the column drop the `NOT NULL`  constraint.